# Get the validator from the parent via the form control

Tags: angular

I have a custom component. From the parent, through the control forms. I am passing a validator. How do I catch it inside my component?

Parent:

```
this.formControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
Validators.pattern(REGEX_PAC_CODE)])
```

Custom component:

```
<code-entry [formControl]="formControl"></code-entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create @input for formgroup and formcontrol variable like Below in your custom component.

```
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() formControl: string;
```

pass this values from parent component like below

```
<code-entry [formGroup]="myGroup" [formControl]="myFormcontrol" >
```

While creating formcontrol add validator it the same you can access it inside your custom component using formGroup like below:

```
this.formGroup.controls['myFormcontrol'].parent.validator
```